# Add a uiimageview inside a uiview when touching the uivew

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, uitouch

What I want to do is when I touch the `UIView`, I want to add an image at the touched location.

This is my code I have for the moment.
(I have tried to replace x and y with `touchLocation` in the `CGRectMake`, but that doesn't work).

**Edited**
After clean and restart xcode it work.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

    if ([touch view] == GrassView) {

        NSLog(@"Hit grass");

        UIImageView *imageViewFlower =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,50,50)];
        imageViewFlower.center = touchLocation;
        imageViewFlower.image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteflower.png"];
        [GrassView addSubview:imageViewFlower];

    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: when you execute this code, what is happening?

Comment: @user3266053, open a new question if this is solved, please do not add other questions. Answers get misleading in this way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change the `imageViewFlower` insertion code in the `if` branch with the following code:

```
UIImageView *imageViewFlower =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(touchLocation.x-25,touchLocation.y-25,50,50)];
imageViewFlower.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteflower.png"];
[GrassView addSubview:imageViewFlower];
```

Answer (score 0):

After clean and restart xcode the code works fine.